# Recommended way to implement swipe menu in fragment activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

**Details:**

My app has a main activity that has a static layout for header and footer. The middle part of the screen is represented by fragments which are handled based on user interactions

[image]

**What I want to achieve**

I have a fragment that has menu options in it, I'd like to be able to implement swipe left or right to bring up the menu options. When the user is done, swipe back and revert to another fragment. This swipe will only be made between the one active fragment and the menu fragment.
What would be the most simple and efficient way to code this ?

Right now I have in my activity layout a LinearLayout which will handle fragments

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
```

And when I want to switch the fragment I use:

```
fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.layFragment);

final FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.layFragment, new FragmentOperation());
ft.commit();
```

Beside this, I need to somehow implement the menu swipe.

Comment: ViewPager from support v4 library... Menu code you can get from dashboard from google io app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with ViewPager approach using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter and seems to work fine.